# Table/Grid using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I just started developing an MFC application for the first time and I'm hoping to get more familiar with the whole "controls" concept. I am using the dialog editor in visual studio and so far I was not able to find functionality to add a simple table/grid. It seems quite basic to me, but I can't even find reliable information on how to do it on the internet.
I am looking for something similar to Qt's QTableWidget, something that I can later program with variable amount of rows and columns tailored to my application's use cases.
Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Don't use MFC if you are just trying *"to get more familiar with the whole 'controls' concept"*. MFC **expects** that you are familiar with the Windows API. Trying to understand MFC without knowing the Windows API has not ever worked out.

Comment: @IInspectable I got to be honest with you here. I learnt Visual C++ (to the extent that I have) with "Teach Yourself Visual C++ in ..." books. I did have C / C++ knowledge but not  any specific Windows API knowledge. That came later for me but even then, I only know a bit of that. I could certainly not write a native Win32 app with a "main" function equivalent and message pump etc.

Comment: @and I'm not sure what to answer. You state, that you don't know what you're missing, but then go on to claim with the same confidence, that it cannot possibly be much, significant, or vital. If you want to make a point, that knowing the Windows API were not a prerequisite for proficient MFC use, you'd have to invest time to get up to speed with the former. Only then could you make that claim in a meaningful way. Once you arrive there, you'll understand that you cannot construct a house without a solid foundation.

Comment: Indeed. Not really trying to make any point. I was utterly ignorant to the Win32 concept when I started. Didn’t know about it. I have only started to learn bits about that along the way and eventually realised that MFC is a wrapper for it. I agree with you. Learn to use a saw before a electric one to get a principles. That is my official training- carpentry!!! Many years ago.

Comment: @IInspectable Much of MFC is really just a paper thin wrapper around the Win32 API. I learnt MFC first and then realized I already knew much of Win32 by the time I left MFC behind.

Comment: There are also some good 3rd party controls out there that are much easier to use and much more feature rich than the CListCtrl.  MFC's implementation of the CListCtrl is not something I would call a good implementation of a "grid control", it's just a List Control in Report mode, with all the caveats that come with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [`CGridCtrl`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27) which is very powerful and does a lot of the legwork for you.

Comment: I know a littler about that one... just a little... Chris improved it a lot. Originally it was just a one week demo to prove that a grid could be written in MFC and that it could be cross compiled to Unix using Bristol's Wind/U toolkit. Nice to hear it's working 24 years later.

Comment: Plus1. I've also used this in a project & it's quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after a [List View Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview), which is wrapped by MFC's [`CListCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019) class. The dialog editor will enable you to add one and set its properties.